# Does IIS work with http-only WCF services?

Tags: wcf, iis, tcp

I'm not a WCF expert, so please don't laugh at me.
I need to write a WCF service that receives data through TCP endpoint, not HTTP. Can I still deploy it to IIS or Azure and take advantage of all cool stuff that's baked in (load distribution, etc.)?

Comment: Depends on the version of IIS. IIS v6 supports **HTTP only** - but with IIS v7, you also get *WAS* (Windows Activation Services) which then also supports TCP and other protocol when hosted in IIS.

Comment: I guess there should be an option on SO 'Mark comment as accepted answer' :)

Comment: There - made it an answer, so you can accept it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the version of IIS.

- **IIS v6** supports HTTP only
- with **IIS v7**, you also get WAS (Windows Process Activation Services) which then also supports TCP and other protocol when hosted in IIS

See:

- [How to: Host a WCF Services in IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx)
- [Setting up a netTcpBinding enabled service in IIS 7](http://galratner.com/blogs/net/archive/2010/10/08/setting-up-a-nettcpbinding-enabled-wcf-service-in-iis-7.aspx)